# Customize Avatar using user meta

Tags: user-meta, gravatar

I have a customer where all the users are synchronized through an API every night. This API gives me the profile picture for each user and it is stored as a user meta with `meta_key = 'image'`.

Is there an action, so I can replace the default image in `wp-admin/users.php` with an URL from a user_meta field?

Comment: Yes there is a filter `get_avatar`. Check this [example](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/get_avatar#Example)